# What's the equivalent of xfontsel for fontconfig fonts?

Tags: fonts, x11, fontconfig

I'm trying to draw a particular font in a particular style, using Xft and fontconfig. I know it's possible, because font-manager will let me preview it. (Terminus, in italics, FWIW.)

However, I cannot seem to figure out the right font name to pass to XftFontOpenName to actually make it show up in my program.

Back in the old X font days, I could use `xfontsel` to browse fonts and get it to show me the precise XLFD font name needed to get what I'm looking at. Does anything like that exist for fontconfig?

Comment: ...I've just discovered gtkfontsel, which is exactly what I'm looking for, and no longer exists. Sigh.

Comment: I suspect it wants to load the font based on its font-stored family and name, which you can find out with various tools like fontforge, or TTX, orthe Adobe FDK's tx - also, not sure if useful to you, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078247/linux-c-xft-how-to-use-it seems to be able a similar issue

Comment: I was searching for the same program. In the end I decided to write my own fontconfig variant of xfontsel. Took my spare time of 2 weeks...